# Nextflow showing submitted output as null

Tags: groovy, workflow, nextflow

I have a NextFlow pipeline with 4 processes. And each process is taking the output from the previous process.
Say, here is the `manin.nf` file,

```
  process one {
     publishDir "${params.outputDir}/filtered", mode: 'copy'
     input:
       set pop, file(pl_files) from plink_data

    output:
        file "${pop}_filtered.{bed,fam,bim}" into pling2_results
 
    script:
      output_file = "${pop}_filtered"
      base        = pl_files[0].baseName

    """#script
    """}

    process two {

     input:
      file(vcf) from pling2_results.view()
      

    output:
        file("${base}.vcf") into annotated
 
    script:
     base          = vcf[0].baseName
    """
   #script2
   """
```

And when I execute the workflow as,

```
Nextflow --run main.nf
```

it shows,

```
   [fb/d28447] Submitted process > one (2)
[ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bed, ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bim, ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.fam]
[fb/40bd45] Submitted process > one (1)
[ukb_FE_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bed, ukb_FE_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bim, ukb_FE_50k_exome_seq_filtered.fam]
[0d/b2ff22] Submitted process > two (Runing VEP on ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq)
```

**What I am expecting is,**

my process `two` would run for both, `ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered` and `ukb_FE_50k_exome_seq_filtered` outputs from process `one`. Currently, it is only executing `ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered`.

Where the process `one` is generating 2 output files. Somehow, the process `two` is not able to identify that one.

I would like to know what could be the potential reason for the submitted process showing as null?

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: change `file(vcf) from pling2_results` to       `file(vcf) from pling2_results.view()` to see if your `pling2_results` channel expects what you expect it to contain.

Comment: Thanks, it is showing one of the two outputs, however, I am expecting 2 outputs and in the `outputDir`  there are two outputs.

Comment: I have a question, whether `vcf[0].baseName` means only the first element?

Comment: `vcf[0].baseName` gets the baseName of the first element of vcf, if vcf contains `['/path/to/file1.fastq.gz, /path/to/file2.fastq.gz]' base becomes `/path/to/file1.fastq`

Comment: Ok, I see. I have more than one output from each process. But the next subsequent process is only taking one of the first outputs from the previous processes and not the second one. Even using the channel itself as input. Does the `publishdir` mode copy has an impact on this?

Comment: Put a `.view()` on  each channel and edit your question showing your nextflow command line output so we don't have to guess what's going on :)

Comment: it seems to me that output `file("${base}.vcf.gz") into pling2_results` can never generate `[ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bed, ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.bim, ukb_SPB_50k_exome_seq_filtered.fam]` as output channel. Does your show code match what you ran to generate the nextflow console output?

Comment: The `.bed files and other files` are generated from process one, process `two` can only generate `vcf` and `.html` files as outputs. I am stuck in the process `two`, where it is only taking one output from process `one`